# Get clean public URL from firebase storage (without token)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I was working in an android project but i need to retrieve the Url from firebase as Public because the api i use only accept only Url with an ending of '.jpg' .

I have tried many ways but no changes.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/thirdeye-65bff.appspot.com/o/hh%20(51).jpg?alt=media&token=624b955a-b380-41ee-b5bb-fe402fa1298e

i need it as

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/thirdeye-65bff.appspot.com/o/hh%20(51).jpg

without any tokens is that possible in android or in firebase?

Comment: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

There's unfortunately no way for you to  modify that URL in that way and still keep it working.

The closest I can think of is simply appending `&.jpg` at the end, which does keep it working. But if the  the API doesn't accept it in that format, you're out of luck as far as download URLs go.

In that case the alternative that comes to mind is to set up your own Cloud Functions end-point that reads the image from Cloud Storage and returns it. That way you have more control over the URL format.

Comment: @Puf thank you sir for your response.. but sir can you please give me more explanation on the last line.. 